# How do you avoid column name conflicts?

Tags: mysql, sql, conflict

I was recently assigned a task of creating an auction system. During my work, I met numerous occasions where my SQL queries that contained joins failed to execute due to ambiguous column names. Consider this (simplified) table structure for the auction:

table `auction`:

- `id`
- `name`
- `uid` (ID of the user that created the auction)

table `item`:

- `id`
- `name`
- `uid` (ID of the user that added the item)
- `aid` (ID of the auction where the item is available)
- `price` (initial price)

table `user`:

- `id`
- `name`

table `bid`:

- `id`
- `uid` (ID of the user that placed a bid)
- `iid` (item whose price has been raised)
- `price` (offered price)

As you can see, there are numerous columns that have conflicting names. Joining these tables requires using some measures that will clear the ambiguities.

I can think of two ways to do this. First is to rename the columns, prefixing all of them with an abbreviated table name, so that auction ID will become `a_id`, item ID will become `i_id`, and item ID within the `bid` table will become `b_i_id`. This is pretty solid, but reduces the readability of the column names.

Another way I can think of is writing explicit queries:

```
SELECT `bid`.`id`, `user`.`name`, `bid`.`price`
FROM `bid`
JOIN `item` ON `item`.`id` = `bid`.`iid`
JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id` = `bid`.`uid`
JOIN `auction` ON `auction`.`id` = `item`.`aid`
WHERE `bid`.`price` > `item`.`price`
AND `auction`.`id` = 1
GROUP BY `user`.`id`
ORDER BY `bid`.`price` DESC;
```

This is readable and unambiguous, but requires lots of extra keystrokes.

I use the second approach, but maybe there are others that you have successfuly used in similar situations? How do you avoid column name conflicts in your SQL queries?

Comment: If `keystrokes` are a concern when you program, you need to reconsider your career path!

Comment: @Richard: OK, you got me with this one, this remark deserves a +1 :)

Comment: Drop the backticks `, these have nothing to do with SQL (check the standards!) and save some keystrokes.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi It's not just `keystrokes`; it makes the view rigid.  It can easily create silent problems where a column is added to a table, but the view is not updated with it.  I know that *theoretically* everyone should type out all the fields all the time, but often people use programs that automatically map the columns for them, e.g. PowerBI, EntityFramework, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is that that the benefits of the *extra keystrokes* outweighs the short time it takes to type them *by far* in the long run, at latest when you need to look at a query that you have written a year ago or so.

Answer (score 14):

May be you can try using [aliases](http://www.chapter31.com/2008/08/22/mysql-alias-just-like-table-names-are-case-sensitive-on-nix/) on the table names ?

```
select * from table1 as T1
join table2 as t2 on (t1.key=t2.foreignkey)
```

Comment: This is what I do, but after many nested joins I still feel the same pain points.

Answer (score 5):

[You need to use `AS` alias.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

You can give a table or a column another name by using an alias. This can be a good thing to do if you have very long or complex table names or column names.

An alias name could be anything, but usually it is short.

Comment: You don't need `AS` to use an alias.

Comment: @Frank Heikens: I know but using that keyword is good practice :)

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is correct, but you can also provide an alias for your table:

```
SELECT a.* FROM TableA A
```

in here you can refer to TableA as simply A.

Answer (score 4):

The golden rule of thumb is that if you are ever using more than one table at all, alias the tables, and explicitly alias all columns.

This consistency will get you deep into the force, young padawan.

Answer (score 3):

Change your naming convention so that each data element has a unique name in the schema e.g. `auction_id`, `bid_id`, `user_id`, etc. Ideally the name of the data element will not change between tables but sometimes you will need to add a qualifier to create a synonym e.g. `adding_user_id` and `bidding_user_id` if `user_id` appeared twice in the same table. You should document data element names and their synonyms in a data dictionary.

Comment: Agreed, but by the time most people get to this dilemma, they already are deep into a system with no documentation of this kind, which means spend weeks of work to remediate a problem someone else created =(

Answer (score 0):

You can also define the table column beside the table name:

```
SELECT P.*,T.name AS type FROM <TABLE-A> AS P LEFT JOIN <TABLE-B> AS T ON P.id=T.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'rank

after executing the following query:

> insert into my_table (rank) values (1);

Because `rank` column name clashes with sql keyword `rank`.

**SOLUTION:**

I've added ***back quotes*** to `rank` column name and problem was solved:

> insert into my_table (`rank`) values (1);

Another way to solve the problem is to use ***table name*** instead of ***back quotes***:

> insert into my_table (my_table.rank) values (1);