# Correct this sql statement for Insert into, select, delete

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2008

```
INSERT INTO Checkout(ProductID, MemberID, Quantity) 
  SELECT ProductID, MemberID, Quantity 
    FROM Cart 
    WHERE (MemberID = MemberID) 
  DELETE FROM CART WHERE (MemberID = MemberID)
```

The sql statement is workable until the Select, WHERE part but once I add the delete statement then the error (syntax error missing operator in query expression) comes out. The second MemberID is a value I gave for first MemberID parameter. Please help me to solve this as after I transfer the data from first table to second table then I need to delete the data from first table.

[Edit] Thanks to you all suggestions and now I realized that for WHERE (MemberID = MemberID)
will import entire table to new table and this statement also will delete the entire table contents. What can I do to make sure that the sql statement only delete the particulars members item?

Main Page>Member login page>Buy something>Item stored in shopping cart database (with member id)>display only particular member's bought item in shopping cart> proceed to checkout(only display that member item, delete shopping cart item)

Comment: If you hit four spaces before a code snippet things will be formatted and highlighted a bit better (can also use newlines inside such a code snippet), making it easier to help out.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to define with your `WHERE MemberID = MemberID` clause?? Right now - this is always true and thus will delete **all your rows** from the `Cart` table....

Comment: @KayLee: in that case, you need to somehow store that member's ID into a separate SQL variables, e.g. `@MemberID` and then use that: `WHERE MemberID = @MemberID`

Comment: i have tried tat and it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the second "MemberID".  This needs to be a constant or have a variable name that doesn't conflict with the field name.  A number of techniques for disambiguation are shown in a related SO post:  [How do you avoid column name conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090513/how-do-you-avoid-column-name-conflicts)

Comment: i changed the value to other name and it still wont work. if i change the value name other than memberid , not even the insert query will work!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what **version** of SQL Server you're using - but you might be able to use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) for the `DELETE` statement to achieve what you're looking for. The `OUTPUT` clause was introduced in SQL Server 2005, so if you're on 2005 or newer, this code snippet should work for you:

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.CART 
OUTPUT deleted.ProductID, deleted.MemberID, deleted.Quantity
  INTO dbo.Checkout(ProductID, MemberID, Quantity) 
WHERE MemberID = @MemberID
```

Basically this runs the `DELETE` statement against your `dbo.Cart` table, and it captures what rows have been deleted; those are then in turn inserted into the `dbo.Checkout` table.

<strike>Also - that condition in the `WHERE` clause seems quite funny - basically, this will select and thus delete **all rows** from your table......</strike>

**Update:** I'm assuming you somehow store the relevant member's ID in `@MemberID` and use that to select the rows to delete from the `dbo.Cart` table..

Comment: yes i now realised the condition will copy and delete the entire table contents. how can i set the condition that only the particular member item will be copied and deleted?

Comment: @KayLee: well, that's up to you to know which members you want to delete..... what do you base that decision on?? We cannot possibly know that......

Comment: @KayLee: in that case, you need to somehow store that member's ID into a separate SQL variables, e.g. `@MemberID` and then use that: `WHERE MemberID = @MemberID`

Answer (score 0):

Store your passing data to a newly declared variable and use that variable to everywhere as below, this will work fine, thanks

```
DECLARE @PassedMemberID INT
SET @PassedMemberID = MemberID --Store your passing MemberID here for later use

INSERT INTO Checkout(ProductID, MemberID, Quantity) 
    SELECT ProductID, MemberID, Quantity 
    FROM Cart 
    WHERE (MemberID = @PassedMemberID) 
DELETE FROM CART WHERE (MemberID = @PassedMemberID)
```

Comment: Hello @KayLee, sorry for late reply, unintentionally my query was incomplete, however, according to your question what I understand: you're passing value as `MemberID` which I stored in a variable and then I'm using that to each statement, would you please let me know your result or if you have any comment, thanks for your time.