# Performant array join?

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to apply the same concept for **array of associatives arrays** than in SQL. Here is below an example of users and theirs addresses, and below the desired output of a function called `array_join(array $array1, array $array2, string $key1, string $key2, string $new_key)`

**Users**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Foo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Baz
        )

)
```

**Addresses**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [street] => 53 Van Ness St
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 1
            [street] => 21 Overland St
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [user_id] => 1
            [street] => 101 Mountfort St
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [user_id] => 3
            [street] => 27 Sidney St
        )

)
```

(to summary, user 1 have 3 addresses, and user 3 have one)

**Desired output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John
            [addresses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [street] => 53 Van Ness St
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [street] => 21 Overland St
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [street] => 101 Mountfort St
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Foo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Baz
            [addresses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [user_id] => 3
                            [street] => 27 Sidney St
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now what I came up with is this:

```
<?php

function array_join(&$array1, $array2, $key1, $key2, $new_key) {
    foreach( $array1 as $index1 => $row1 ) {
        foreach( $array2 as $index2 => $row2 ) {
            if( $row2[$key2] === $row1[$key1] ) {
                $array1[$index1][$new_key][] = $row2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this function compute data faster, knowing it takes an average 1.2 sec., which is very high for 6000 rows... How can I optimize this please?

Comment: At least group addresses by user id and then add groups to users.

Comment: How did you get the 1.2s? It is really long for the example array, the two loop only with countable times. `$t1 = microtime(); foreach and forach; $diff = microtime() - $t1; echo $diff`. Did you get the time in this way?

Comment: Is the 1.2 second timing for this PHP only? Or the query as well?

Comment: And if these are rows from database - move to query with `JOIN` instead of 2 queries and further processing.

Comment: Are this arrays from the DB. maybe you get result by a query?

Comment: Instead of reimplementing DB operations in PHP, just use a DB instead.

Comment: @ildflue The average 1.2s is only the `array_left_join` php computing. I did like you wrote, wrapping `microtime(true)` around the function basically.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes only PHP computing.

Comment: @u_mulder moving from 2 queries to one will prevent using benefits of nested "relations" because if you query 2 tables with columns having the same names your first table will overrite the column with the same name (in this example you would have only one `id` column related to the user instead of one `id` for the user and one `id` for the adress).

Comment: @Sammitch for the issues regarding my last answer I cannot (I googled it before).

Comment: Did you ever hear about column aliases?

Comment: @u_mulder I've also tryied to prefix all my columns by the table name (but here is the first issue, when your users requested `*` and you have to perform either a `SELECT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` or to fetch 1 row and get all columns names), but the cost of having n rows equals to the number of adresses, and grouping them by a similar key, plus removing bulky prefixes for the user not to fetch his data by `$users->{'user.name'}` but `$user->name` is very high compared to a `array_left_join` unfortunately. Open to discuss.

Comment: wat? you need to post your *actual* mysql problem in the mysql tag so that you can get a *sane* solution instead of pursuing this bizarre XY problem in the php tag. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Sammitch My bad for tagging this issue as MySQL `join` tag. This have been removed somehow.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that trying to solve this problem in PHP is foolish. You have a simple problem with a mysql query that you haven't been able to solve, and posting *that* as a *different* question in the MySQL tag will get you a *far better solution* than trying to reimplement JOIN logic in PHP

Comment: @Sammitch [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090513/how-do-you-avoid-column-name-conflicts) does not show any far better solution. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Wat? All the answers there are all directly applicable to your stated problem of "duplicate column names". Table aliases, column aliases, using `table.column`. For the record, I'm not going to respond to any more comments unless it's a link to a mysql tagged question about how to do joins with aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use nested loops. Create an associative array that uses `$key1` as the keys. Then you can just loop through `$array2` and find the matching element of `$array1` without a loop.

```
function array_join(&$array1, $array2, $key1, $key2, $new_key) {
    $assoc_array1 = array();
    // Create an associative array of references to the original array elements, keyed by $key1
    foreach ($array1 as &$row1) {
        $assoc_array1[$row1[$key1]] = $row1;
    }
    // Join the elements of the second array to those elements.
    foreach( $array2 as $row2 ) {
        $assoc_array1[$row2[$key2]][$new_key][] = $row2;
    }
}
```

This is analogous to the way databases use indexes to optimize `JOIN` operations.

Comment: Maybe `array_column` to index.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I want an array of references so that updating them in the second loop will work.

Comment: mind-blowing! gone from average `1.2` to `0.0019682248433431` !! Thanks a lot. Now the fun part: understanding!

Comment: Very clever the use of the index, as I only use it to index my loop, you use it as an anchor point to avoid cross joining the arrays, excellent!

Comment: Any time you find yourself using nested loops (or loops that call functions like `in_array()` or `array_search()`, which have to use loops internally) you should look for ways around it. Nested loops are O(n^2).