# How do I get a SQLite query to return the id of a table when I have two tables that have an attribute named id?

Tags: python, sqlite

I can't seem to find anything on how to access the `id` attribute from the table I want. I have 4 tables that I have joined. User, workouts, exercises, and sets. They all have primary keys with the attribute name `id`.

My query:

```
query = """SELECT users.firstName, workouts.dateandtime, workouts.id, sets.*, exercises.name FROM users
      JOIN workouts ON users.id = workouts.userID JOIN sets ON workouts.id = sets.workoutID JOIN exercises ON
      sets.exerciseID = exercises.id WHERE users.id = ? ORDER BY sets.id DESC"""
```

I'm only grabbing the `workouts.id` and `sets.id` because `user.id` is found when the user logs in and `exercises.id` is cast amongst all users and it's important in this step.

Trying to access the `sets.id` like this does not work:

```
posts_unsorted = cur.execute(query, userID).fetchall()
for e in posts_unsorted:
    print(e['id']) # Prints workouts.id I'm assuming because it's the first id I grab in the query
    print(e['sets.id']) # Error because sets.id does not exist
```

Is there a way to name the `sets.id` when making the query so that I can actually use it? Should I be setting up my database differently to gab the `sets.id`? I don't know what direction I should be going.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you avoid column name conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090513/how-do-you-avoid-column-name-conflicts)

Comment: @Tim That question seems to answer how to make the input easier to read. I need to access the output of both `workouts.id` and `sets.id`. I did not see anything in there about renaming the outputs so they can both be used.

Comment: You use `workouts.id as w_id` in the query

Comment: Ohh you can do that with the output too. I did not see it like that in the link you posted. I thought that was just form making it easier to type in the query.

Comment: @Tim Your comments helped. Did you want to answer the question? I can then accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This post [How do you avoid column name conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090513/how-do-you-avoid-column-name-conflicts). Shows that you can give your tables aliases. This helps make it easier to refer to you tables in queries. It also gives what your query returns direction in what to name everything.

If you have two tables that both have an attribute called `id`. You will need to give them an `alias` to be able to access both attributes.

An example:

```
.schema sets
CREATE TABLE "sets"(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    interval INTEGER NOT NULL,
    workoutID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY id,
    FORGIEN KEY workoutID REFERENCES workouts(id)
);

.schema workouts
CREATE TABLE "workouts"(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    date SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY id,
    FORGIEN KEY workoutID REFERENCES workouts(id)
);
```

Fill the database:

```
INSERT INTO workouts (date) VALUES (2022-03-14), (2022-02-13);
INSERT INTO sets (interval, workoutID) VALUES (5, 1), (4, 1), (3, 2), (2, 2);
```

Both tables have a `primary key` labeled `id`. If you must access both `id`s you will need to add an `alias` in your query.

```
database = sqlite3.connect("name.db")
database.row = sqlite3.Row
cur = database.cursor()
query = """SELECT sets.id AS s_id, workouts.date AS w_date, workouts.id AS w_id 
    FROM sets JOIN workouts ON sets.workoutID=w_id"""
posts = cur.execute(query).fetchall()
```

This will return to you named tuples making to easy to retrieve the data you want. The data will look like this:

```
[{'s_id':1, 'w_date':'2022-03-14', 'w_id':1}, 
{'s_id':2, 'w_date':'2022-03-14', 'w_id':1},
{'s_id':3, 'w_date':'2022-02-13', 'w_id':2},
{'s_id':4, 'w_date':'2022-02-13', 'w_id':2}]
```

With this set of data you will be able to access everything by `name` instead of `index`.